# Insert a dynamic value (category name) as namespace in a route

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

I have a resource called articles. Besides title, author, and content, it has a field called category that is itself another resource. I didn't make a one-to-many relationship but I could. What I would like to do is insert the category name in front of the article title separated by a slash, like the below. Assume one of the categories is "technology".

example.com/articles/technology/some-article-title-slug

I tried making the slug "technology/some-article-title-slug" but rails escaped the forward slash. And I don't want the word "category" in there which rails can do easily with:

```
resources: categories do
  resources: articles
end
```

resulting in example.com/categories/1/articles/some-article-title-slug

And making category name into a slug would be:
example.com/categories/technology/articles/some-article-title-slug

Not very nice.

So how can I get:

example.com/articles/technology/some-article-title-slug

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case anyone has the same question here is how I solved it. I made a custom route, controller action and view for each category. And made a custom route for each category's show page, but used the articles show action and view. This works fine if the number of categories is small. If for example the articles resource has two categories, technology and economics, the routes file would look like:

```
# config/routes.rb
get 'articles/technology/:id', controller: 'articles', action: 'show', as: 'technology_article'
get 'articles/economics/:id', controller: 'articles', action: 'show', as: 'economics_article'
resources :articles do
  get :technology, on: :collection
  get :economics, on: :collection
end
```

In the articles controller I add an action for technology and one for economics.

```
def technology
  @articles = Article.where(category: "technology").order(created_at: :desc)
end
def economics
  @articles = Article.where(category: "economics").order(created_at: :desc)
end
```

And in the articles views I add view pages named technology.html.erb and economics.html.erb that are set up like a standard Rails index.html.erb page, except they include the category name at the top.

Links to these pages would use technology_articles_path and economics_articles_path. 
And links to the individual technology articles would use technology_article_path(article.id).

All articles, regardless of category, would use the same show controller action and view.